# Getting error number returned by recv function

Tags: c, linux, return-value, errno, strerror

How can I get the error number or error string returned by the `recv()` in socket communication, `recv()` returns `-1` as read size which means some error has occurred. I want to know the specific reason for the error. so how can I get that.

Comment: Start by reading the [`recv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html) manual page, especially the section about [the return value](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/recv.2.html#RETURN_VALUE).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to include *errno.h* and use the `errno` global variable to check the last error code. Also, you can use [`strerror()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strerror.3.html) to print a locale aware string explaining the error.

Example

```
#include <errno.h>

ssize_t size;

if ((size = recv( ... )) == -1)
{
    fprintf(stderr, "recv: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno);
}
```

Comment: A common format is: `fprintf(stderr, "recv: %s (%d)\n", strerror(errno), errno)`

Comment: @Ctx I know, but this is very straight forward, so really curious to learn why the downvote, aren't you?

Comment: Maybe the missing `;` at the end of the fprintf disturbs someone? ;)

Comment: You can get downvotes for redundant semicolons?  Hardly worth risking any answer at all, these days:(

Answer (score 3):

You can make use of the [`errno`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/errno) variable from `errno.h` header file.

From the [man page](http://linux.die.net/man/3/recv) (*emphasis mine*)

> #### Return Value
>
> Upon successful completion, `recv()` shall return the length of the message in bytes. If no messages are available to be received and the peer has performed an orderly shutdown, `recv()` shall return 0. **Otherwise, -1 shall be returned and `errno` set to indicate the error.**

Alternatively, you can also call [`perror()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/perror) / [`strerror()`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/strerror) to get a human-readable string related to the error.